# Can't connect to azure ad app from different tenants even after setting app as multi tenant

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I decided to create app from old azure portal and set the app to multi tenant.

I have set the OAuth 2.0 token endpoint (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my tenant id>/oauth2/token`) for token and OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my tenant id>/oauth2/authorize`) for authorization.

If I try to authorize with any registered Office 365 user id, other than user I use to login to azure, then I get this error:

User account 'tester1@testercore.onmicrosoft.com' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/49322bd9-93ea-4911-a8e4-1aa10bc5b680/' does not exist in tenant 'mary' and cannot access the application '8adfad2b-f28a-40a6-8698-8b53ac506132' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

If I manually add this user in azure then I get the access tokens but that shouldn't have been the case. This has to happen runtime since my app is multi tenant. Can you suggest where I might be going wrong ?

Comment: how you configure OpenIdConnect OWIN Middleware?

Comment: @CuongLe I am using OAuth and not openId Connect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize` endpoint.

This is the *common* endpoint that allows login from any Azure AD tenant. You should not use your tenant-specific endpoint in a multi-tenant application.

As for getting the access token, you will have to use the signed-in user's tenant id. This way you get an access token that is only valid in their tenant.

Comment: using https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize doesn't even open the authorization page. Moreover I need this access token to work for any tenant who signs in to use my app . how may I do this ?

Comment: The Url does open the authorization page, if you use it literally without any parameters it shows an UI displaying "AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'." which makes sense because client_id must be provided, so, what you need to do is just replace in your queries your specific tenantId with **common**. When you get the token it will contains claims tid and issuer corresponding to the tenant the user belongs to.

Comment: You can't get an access token that works in any tenant. If your app requires app permissions though, then it will be able to independently get a token for any tenant that has gone through the initial sign up process. I prefer using delegated permissions if possible as it limits what the app can do.